# Finding reported drive errors in Windows RAID

Tags: windows-7, raid

This machine has been through a number of RAID configurations.

Most recently, it had a single drive (Disk 1) installed without mirroring, and without error.

A second drive (Disk 0) was added as a mirror of Disk 1. After some time synching, Windows Disk Management reports that the new Disk 0 is fine, but Disk 1 is reporting errors.

[image]

It surprises me that a good drive would coincidentally start reporting errors after mirrorings. I have been looking for any sign of the errors, but I can't find any mention in the Event logs.

Where can I determine more about the nature of the errors, before I buy a new batch of hard-drives?